# Amazon DynamoDB DAX View cache contents and selective cache clear

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-dax

Is there an option in amazon dynamodb dax to view the contents in the cache and clear the cache selectively?

Comment: No, i don't think there is. The UI console doesn't have one and there's no special DAX API since it's just a wrapper on top of Dynamo APIs.